# How to enable USB mode on Ubuntu Server installed on Raspberry Pi Zero W?

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w

have installed Ubuntu Server on my Raspberry Pi Zero W and I'm trying to enable USB mode. I have edited the cmdline.txt and config.txt files as suggested, but upon booting, the USB mode is not working. Additionally, I have plugged the USB into the second port near the HDMI port, but still no luck.

Any suggestions on how to properly enable USB mode on the Raspberry Pi Zero W running Ubuntu Server would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

My host machine is ubuntu

My config file

```
[all]
kernel=vmlinuz
cmdline=cmdline.txt
initramfs initrd.img followkernel

[pi4]
max_framebuffers=2
arm_boost=1

[all]
# Enable the audio output, I2C and SPI interfaces on the GPIO header. As these
# parameters related to the base device-tree they must appear *before* any
# other dtoverlay= specification
dtparam=audio=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on

# Comment out the following line if the edges of the desktop appear outside
# the edges of your display
disable_overscan=1

# If you have issues with audio, you may try uncommenting the following line
# which forces the HDMI output into HDMI mode instead of DVI (which doesn't
# support audio output)
#hdmi_drive=2

# Enable the serial pins
enable_uart=1

# Autoload overlays for any recognized cameras or displays that are attached
# to the CSI/DSI ports. Please note this is for libcamera support, *not* for
# the legacy camera stack
camera_auto_detect=1
display_auto_detect=1


[cm4]
# Enable the USB2 outputs on the IO board (assuming your CM4 is plugged into
# such a board)
dtoverlay=dwc2

[all]
```

My cmdline.txt file

```
console=serial0,115200 multipath=off dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 rootwait fixrtc modules-load=dwc2,g_ether
```

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? AFAIK there never was an ARM6 version.

Comment: using raspberrypi imager

Comment: perhaps `dtoverlay=dwc2` needs to be placed in a location in that file for the Zero rather than the CM4